# Example of degree $n$ ramified, but not totally ramified extension

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, local-field, ramification, unramified-extension

I'm looking for an example of degree $n$ ramified **but not totally ramified** example over $\Bbb Q_p$.

I can find degree $n$ ramified extension, for example, $\Bbb Q_p({p^{1/n}})/\Bbb Q_p$.
$p^{1/n}$'s minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q_p$ is $x^n-p$ ($p$-eisenstein polynomial) and this is degree $n$, so the extension degree is exactly $n$.
And norm of  ${p^{1/n}}$ is $-p$, this is prime element of $\Bbb Q_p$, so the extension is totally ramified.

But this kind of construction only generates totally ramified cases..
But I'm looking for a degree $n$ and ramified **but not totally ramified**.

Could you give me an example of degree $n$ ramified **but not totally ramified** example over $\Bbb Q_p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is prime, then any extension will be either unramified or totally ramified, because $n=ef$. Suppose that $n$ is not prime and $n=ml$ with $m,l>1$. Take a degree $m$ totally ramified extension, say $\Bbb Q_p(p^{1/m})$ and a degree $l$ unramified extension $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_{w})$ where $w=p^l-1$. Then we can take the composite field $\Bbb Q_p(p^{1/m},\zeta_{w})$ this has degree $ml=n$. Indeed $x^m-p$ is is still Eisenstein over the field $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_w)$ because $p$ is a prime element in the ring of integers (as $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_w)/\Bbb Q_p$ is unramified). Because the ramification index and inertia degree are multiplicative, this extension has ramification index $m$ and inertia degree $l$, so it's ramified, but not totally ramified.

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why the ring of integers is UFD ? (If not, you cannot apply Eisenstein).

Comment: @dandelion the ring of integers of a p-adic field is even a DVR, so a PID and hence a UFD

Comment: No, the coefficient ring is Qp(ζω) 's ring of integers (not Qp). Without showing this ring of integers is UFD, you cannot apply Eisenstein.

Comment: @dandelion when I said "p-adic field", I meant any finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ (so any local field of char 0). It's true that the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_w)$ is a DVR, too.

Comment: Could you give me the reference about that fact or could you give the proof here ?

Comment: @dandelion I think that should be in every book covering local fields, e.g. Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*. The basic idea is that for a finite extension $L/\Bbb Q_p$, there's a unique extension of the p-adic valuation to $L$ and the ring of integers of $L$ is the valuation ring associated to that valuation. But the valuation remains discrete, so the valuation ring is a DVR, hence a PID, hence a UFD.

Comment: Oh, that is clear view. I was troubled because I took DVR as local PID that is not a field, but by seeing characterization by valuation , it was clear.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand what you said. discrete means value group is Z. But extending value, unless the extension is unramified, is not Z because ramification index is not 1. So I don't have confident that I can say any p adic field's integer ring is DVR.

Comment: @dandelion discrete means that the value group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, if $L$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ with ramification index $e$, then the extended valuation will have value group $\frac{1}{e}\Bbb Z$, but that's still isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: But the definition of DVR means value group is exactly Z (as a set) .

Comment: Do you insist that every 「finite extension of the valuation  field whose value group is DVR 」's valuation ring is again DVR ?

Comment: @dandelion yes. If you want a discrete valuation with exactly Z as a valuation group, you can just multiply the extended valuation by the ramification index. This won't change the valuation ring.