# DVR whose value group is not $\mathbb Z$ as a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

DVR(discrete valuation ring) is defined as valuation ring whose value group is isomorphic(as group) to $\mathbb Z$.

Examples of DVR I know ( like $\mathbb Z_p$,$\mathbb Z_{(p)}$) has valuation group $\mathbb Z$ exactly as a set.

But are there DVR whose value group is not $\mathbb Z$(as a set) but $\mathbb Z$(as a grouop)?

**For example, what is an example of a valuation ring whose value group is {$...-3/2,-1/2,0,1/2,3/2,・・・$} as a set?**

Comment: I'm not sure I see what it means for something to be $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group but not as a set. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I suspect that the reason you're asking this question is the comment exchange from this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254547 I'll try one more time to clarify. If you have a DVR $R$ with fraction field $K$ and $L$ is finite extension of $K$, then you can extend the discrete valuation associated to $R$ to $L$. If there is ramification, say in the example $\Bbb Q_p(\sqrt{p})/\Bbb Q_p$ then that extended valuation may have a different value group then $\Bbb Z$ (as a set). In the example we have $\frac{1}{2}\Bbb Z$. But the value group is still isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. (cont.)

Comment: And you can just multiply the valuation by a constant (in the example $2$) to get an equivalent discrete valuation where the value group is $\Bbb Z$ (as a set)

Comment: If we think of (rank 1) valuations as functions to $\Bbb R$, then multiplying a valuation by a constant $r \in \Bbb R$ with $r>0$ yields a new valuation, but it's equivalent to the original valuation and it has the same valuation ring

Comment: @dandelion In your added example, one might argue that this group is also not $\mathbb{Z}$, it is $\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$. Of course, this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group, and in this sense, it "is" $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group. However, if we allow this, the we must allow that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ as a set, so it "is" $\mathbb{Z}$ as a set.

Comment: The short slogan is "to be is to be equivalent".